# Add few components into one view in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, components, extjs

I am new to sencha and i have no idea how to add a few components into my Panel. I can't find any informations about that, so I think that is really easy to implement, and I really don't know how to begin. I like the design which is shown here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kiva/ , but after getting started tutorial, i can't copy this project even in the design way. Please, guys, help me how to handle this...

For example, if I have my main view(Main.js) looking like this:

```
Ext.define("GS.view.Main", {    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],

    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'top',
        cetner: true,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'profile'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'map'        
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

and Position:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Position', {    extend: 'Ext.Map',

    xtype: 'map',

    config: {
        title: 'Position',
        iconCls: 'time',
        useCurrentLocation: true,
        mapOptions: {
            zoom: 19
        },
        listeners: {
            maprender : function(comp, map){
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this._geo.getLatitude(), this._geo.getLongitude()),
                    map: map
                });    



            }


        }
    }
});
```

How to add some additional components into my Position View?

Thanks
Miłosz

Answer (score 0):

First I noticed you have xtype:'map' in your position view, delete that line and replace it with an alias. To call to your position view with a xtype you need to add an alias config like

```
alias:'widget.mymap'
```

Dont just name your alias map because it will confuse sencha.

then in your main view do something like so

```
items: [
        {
           xtype: 'profile'
        },
        {
           xtype: 'mymap'        
        },
        ]
```

Comment: I was looking for some other solution, but really thanks for your suggestion.